# Power builder rtf column does not display simple text

Tags: sql-server, rtf, powerbuilder, datawindow

I need to **convert** some datawindow **text** columns (PB 11.5.1 - SQL Server 2008R2 - datatype Text)  **to RTF**.

I have 2 issues:

- New data are displayed fine but the existing data do not display at
  all
- The RTF format popup has very limited height so the icons are half
  displayed

For the first issue I did find a work around but it is far from elegant!

I append this:

`{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1253\uc1\deff0{\fonttbl  {\f0\fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Arial;}  {\f1\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2 Tahoma;}  {\f2\froman\fcharset2\fprq2 Symbol;}}  {\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}  {\stylesheet{\s0\itap0\nowidctlpar\f0\fs24 [Normal];}{\*\cs10\additive Default Paragraph Font;}}  {\*\generator TX_RTF32 13.0.501.502;}  \deftab1134\paperw3240\paperh16838\margl0\margt0\margr0\margb0\widowctrl  {\*\background{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpleft0\shptop0\shpright0\shpbottom0\shpfhdr0\shpbxmargin\shpbxignore\shpbymargin\shpbyignore\shpwr0\shpwrk0\shpfblwtxt1\shplid1025{\sp{\sn shapeType}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fillColor}{\sv 12506623}}{\sp{\sn fFilled}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn lineWidth}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fLine}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fBackground}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fLayoutInCell}{\sv 1}}}}}\pard\itap0\nowidctlpar\plain\f1\fs20`

before the text and add a `}` in the end.

I hope there is another way that does not include changing the actual data!

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little cleaner to use the **PasteRTF** PowerBuilder function for existing data. Technically this doesn't solve your concern about changing data as the function probably adds the RTF tags much like you are doing manually.

As another method that might work is to try using a separate **RichTextEdit** control and the **DataSource** function. The DataSource function allows a RichTextEdit control to share data with a DataWindow and display the data in its input fields. If there are input fields in the RichTextEdit control that match the names of columns in the DataWindow, the data in the DataWindow is assigned to those input fields. I'd look at the InputFieldNamesVisible property also because it affects what is displayed.

This example from the Help File establishes the DataWindow control dw_1 as the data source for the RichTextEdit rte_1. Using a template document might be a way around your challenge of displaying data, but not actually changing it- not sure I have not used this myself.

```
rte_1.DataSource(dw_1)
```

This example inserts a document called LETTER.RTF into the RichTextEdit rte_letter (the names of the document's input fields match the columns in a DataWindow object d_emp), creates a DataStore, associates it with d_emp, and retrieves data. Then it inserts the document in rte_letter and sets up the DataStore as the data source for rte_1:

```
DataStore ds_empinfo
ds_empinfo = CREATE DataStore
ds_empinfo.DataObject = "d_emp"
ds_empinfo.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
ds_empinfo.Retrieve()

rte_letter.InsertDocument("LETTER.RTF", TRUE)
rte_letter.DataSource(ds_empinfo)
```

As far as the icon question - I am not aware of a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you Rich! I will try some of these.